# Python Split Different List

Tags: python, list, split

I have a list that I am trying to split into a pandas data frame. I can split simple lists by comma, but there are commas in the values that I need to split. Here is the way my list is setup:

```
[{'Name':'Smith, John','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith@so.com'},
 {'Name':'Smith, Jane','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 5, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith2@so.com'},
 {'Name':'Doe, Monica','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 3, 0, 0),'Email Address':'MDoe@so.com'}]
```

I have tried various ways to split the data, but it always comes out odd. The expected result should have been:

```
    Name           Date of Birth        Email Address
0   Smith, John    05-10-2016           JSmith@so.com
1   Smith, Jane    06-05-2010           JSmith2@so.com
2   Doe, Monica    10-03-2012           MDoe@so.com
```

but I keep getting things like below where the title is still in the column.

```
'Name':'Smith, John'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should show your code, its not clear how you're getting things like that given you're passing in a list of dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does passing the list into `pandas.DataFrame()` not work?

```py
import pandas
import datetime

l = [{'Name':'Smith, John','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith@so.com'},
     {'Name':'Smith, Jane','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 5, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith2@so.com'},
     {'Name':'Doe, Monica','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 3, 0, 0),'Email Address':'MDoe@so.com'}]

df  = pandas.DataFrame(l)
print(df)
```

gives me:

```
  Date of Birth   Email Address         Name
0    2016-05-10   JSmith@so.com  Smith, John
1    2010-06-05  JSmith2@so.com  Smith, Jane
2    2012-10-03     MDoe@so.com  Doe, Monica
```

Comment: It seems as if it is the simple solution that makes the most sense. I was trying to loop through the list and splitting them, and them appending them to a DataFrame. This is much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [{'Name':'Smith, John','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0,      0),'Email Address':'JSmith@so.com'},
{'Name':'Smith, Jane','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 5, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith2@so.com'},
{'Name':'Doe, Monica','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 3, 0, 0),'Email Address':'MDoe@so.com'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

The output of df will be:

```
 Date of Birth   Email Address         Name
0    2016-05-10   JSmith@so.com  Smith, John
1    2010-06-05  JSmith2@so.com  Smith, Jane
2    2012-10-03     MDoe@so.com  Doe, Monica
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just pass that into a `pandas.DataFrame()` call and it'll work more-or-less as you want (but with the indentation/justification changed up slightly):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_list = [{'Name':'Smith, John','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2016, 5, 10, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith@so.com'},
...  {'Name':'Smith, Jane','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2010, 6, 5, 0, 0),'Email Address':'JSmith2@so.com'},
...  {'Name':'Doe, Monica','Date of Birth':datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 3, 0, 0),'Email Address':'MDoe@so.com'}]
>>> x = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
>>> print(x)
          Name Date of Birth   Email Address
0  Smith, John    2016-05-10   JSmith@so.com
1  Smith, Jane    2010-06-05  JSmith2@so.com
2  Doe, Monica    2012-10-03     MDoe@so.com
```